# Correctly substituting a matrix into a scalar equation

Tags: matrix, syntax, linear-algebra

I am having trouble correctly substituting a matrix into an (originally) scalar equation.

For example:

```
A = {{3, 1}, {1, 2}}
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x]
```

which produces x^2-5x+5

It is known that the characteristic polynomial must be equal to zero.
Using:

```
cp /. {x -> A}
```

We obtain `{{-5,  0}, {0, -5}},` but the correct answer is `{{0, 0},{0, 0}}` or,

```
MatrixPower[A, 2] - 5 A + 5 IdentityMatrix[2]
```

I have toyed with the idea of using `CoefficientList` and an `If` statement inside of a `For` loop, then matching the coefficients with their respective `MatrixPower` and multiplying the final `CoefficientList[A, x, 0]` by the identity matrix. But, this seems unnecessarily complex and not general enough to work for all characterist polynomial forms.

Can anyone think of an elegant way to raise the matrix to the correct power using `MatrixPower` and also only multiply the constant term by the identity matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes straight from the documentation on [`CharacteristicPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CharacteristicPolynomial.html). Look at the section Examples > Properties & Relations.

```
m = {{3, 1}, {1, 2}};
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[m, x]
```

> ```
> 5 - 5 x + x^2
> ```

```
cl = CoefficientList[cp, x];
Sum[MatrixPower[m, j - 1] cl[[j]], {j, 1, Length[cl]}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: To avoid opening another question, is there an easy way to solve CharacteristicPolynomial for the highest power? In this example, set cp=5(x-1)? Obviously I can do cp=-(cp-x^2) but is there a better way?

Comment: @gKirkland. Please do open a new question on this new issue. We like to keep questions focused to one issue whenever we can.